# slice operator understanding

Tags: python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [good primer for python slice notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/good-primer-for-python-slice-notation)

I am a little confused as to what the slice operator does in python.  Can anyone explain to me how it works?

Comment: If you mean slicing, this is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/good-primer-for-python-slice-notation

Answer (score 7):

The slice operator is a way to get items from lists, as well as change them. See http://docs.python.org/tutorial/introduction.html#lists.

You can use it to get parts of lists, skipping items, reversing lists, and so on:

```
>>> a = [1,2,3,4]
>>> a[0:2] # take items 0-2, upper bound noninclusive
[1, 2]
>>> a[0:-1] #take all but the last
[1, 2, 3]
>>> a[1:4]
[2, 3, 4]
>>> a[::-1] # reverse the list
[4, 3, 2, 1]
>>> a[::2] # skip 2
[1, 3]
```

The first index is where to start, the (optional) second one is where to end, and the (optional) third one is the step.

And yes, this question is a duplicate of [Explain Python's slice notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/good-primer-for-python-slice-notation).